# Removing a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Since I used scaffolding to create my Deposit model,

```
resources :deposits
```

generates a bunch of routes. i want to be able to delete some of those routes for particular models. For example I do not want a "deposts/23/edit" route. I know I can do a redirect in the controller or do a

```
match "deposits/:id/edit", :to => "deposit#new"
```

which just shows the new deposit page but does not change the url on the browser.

is there a way to completely remove a certain action through declaring something in the rails routes.rb file. so that particular actions are just not accessible.

Comment: An important concept in Rails is REST and how websites should respond to requests. Why do you want to delete the ever useful edit route from that resource?

Comment: I actually wanted to not let the user edit a particular transaction that is already created by simply entering the URL to it and going there. In essence, I just want to be able to limit my users from accessing a particular model's edit view on production, thats all. I was hoping to keep the view still around and accessible on Dev for testing and data manipulation purpose

Comment: Look into permissions management, CanCan should acomplish what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reccomend looking over the [Ruby on Rails Guide for Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) it discuses important core concepts and presents you with some good information on how routes are wired the way they are.

If you still wish to remove the edit route you will find a useful part of the guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created) the code you need is listed below:

```
resources :deposits, :except => :edit
```

Answer (score 2):

resources :deposits, :only => { :create, :new }

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :deposits, :except => :edit
```